# webpack-dev-server: getting a 404 on an AJAX redirect

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I'm implementing the OAuth2 flow on an ReactJS app that uses `webpack-dev-server` and `react-router` BrowserRouter.

I have two flows. The first one works without problems, second does not:

app does a **browser redirect** to the auth provider **>>** user logs in, auth provider **redirects back** to the app (localhost:3000/login) **>>** app on **/login** route completes the flow.

If I want to check the login status when a user, say, refreshes the page:

app makes an **AJAX call** to the auth provider **>>** since there's a session, auth provider **redirects back** to the app (localhost:3000/login) **>>** AJAX call **fails with a 404**.

My webpack config:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': null,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Looks like the `historyApiFallback` option is not kicking in for AJAX calls...

Comment: How are you fetching the login status?  Are you using cookies?  For OAuth flow are you using the react-oauth-flow module?

Comment: Yes, with cookies via `withCredentials: true`. No module, just an regular AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 devServer: {
        port: 3001,
        contentBase: 'public', // public is where your index.html is located
        hot: true,
        stats:{
            colors: true
        },
        quiet: false,
        host: "localhost",
        overlay: true,
        historyApiFallback: {
            disableDotRule: true,
        },
    },
```

Comment: Can you explain your suggestion? Is it `disableDotRule: true`, `contentBase: 'public'`, both?

Comment: the `disableDotRule` is not the main point. it only ignores any dots if have some in your path. `contentBase:'public'` is the key here.

I am assuming that your project might look like this

```
project
--public
--public/index.html
--src/app.js
--webpack.js
```
https://github.com/EnetoJara/eneto-react-init/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.js